# Display multiple XML nodes into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax

I'm trying to display all the nodes of an specific tag, so far it does filter the data I want but only one node showsup. Can somebody help me please?

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<USA>
<NY>
  <Cell>NY Store 1</Cell>
   <Cell>NY Store 2</Cell>
  <Cell>NY Store 3</Cell>
</NY>
<CA>
  <Cell>CA Store 1</Cell>
   <Cell>CA Store 2</Cell>
  <Cell>CA Store 3</Cell> 
</CA>
</USA>
```

Here's the Script:

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    var txt,x,i;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    txt="";
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CA");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
    xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("Cell");
    }
    try
    {
    txt=txt + xx[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br />";
    }
    catch (er)
    {
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=txt;
    }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","stores.xml",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

and here's the HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">California</button>
<div id="result">Please select your state</div>
```

As I said, it words fine, but its only showing one element under California. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xx is also an array, so you need another loop inside x loop.

try catch need to be inside this loop.

I am not very good at javascript, but if your syntax is correct. So, I think this may work (I didn't test it though):

```
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
    xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("Cell");
    for(j=0;j<xx.length;j++) {
       try {
          txt=txt + xx[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br />";
       }
       catch(er) {

       }
    }
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=txt;
```